# Solving a 4th order polynomial

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I have a fourth order polynomial of the form:
$$y = a_{0} + a_1 x + a_{2}x^{2} + a_{3}x^{3} + a_{4}x^{4}$$
Where the coefficients $a_{0}$, $a_{1}$, $a_{2}$, $a_{3}$ and $a_{4}$ are determined from the result of a fit, and are real numbers. How can I solve this equation in terms of x where $y$ is both real and positive? $x$ should be real, but not necessarily positive.

Comment: Complex solutions come in pairs, so if there is a real root, there must be a second (and possibly a third and fourth). Which one do you want?

Comment: @JohnDoty Thanks for the reply, I guess all of them and I'd like to use  test them so I can make a prediction for $x$ based on what $y$ is, which is known to me.

Comment: Do you want to solve for `x` or "in terms of `x`"?  Isn't `y` already in terms of `x`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I want to solve for x.

Comment: Maybe `Solve[poly == y && y > 0 && x \[Element] Reals, x]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.

Comment: Use `NSolve` for inexact problems.

Comment: @JohnDoty Can you give me a syntax example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the `Solve::ratnz` message per se.  It's just notifying the user of how the solution was computed.  Since `Solve` is purportedly an exact solver, it notifies the user that some rounding may have occurred in computing the solution, in case the user wishes to control the rounding themselves.

Here is a constructed example, which can be analyzed, since it is known what function is being approximated (`Exp[x]`):

```
p = InterpolatingPolynomial[{#, Exp@N@#} &[{-2., -1.5, 0., 1.5, 2.}] // Transpose, x];
datarange = {-2., 2.};
sols = x /. Solve[p == y && y > 0 && datarange[[1]] < x < datarange[[2]], x];
Plot[{Log[y], sols} // Flatten // Evaluate, {y, Exp[-2], Exp[2]}]
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now a degree-4 equation $p(x) = y$ is going to have, generically, 0, 2, or 4 real roots, and never just 1 except at one value of `y`, namely an absolute extremum of $p(x)$.  Hence, I used `datarange[[1]] < x < datarange[[2]]` to exclude a spurious solution.  Here `datarange` is an interval of feasible values for `x`.  Implicitly, I'm assuming that extrapolation is to be avoided, and `datarange` was chosen to be the range of the `x` coordinates in the data.  If extrapolation is acceptable, then `datarange` may be set to an appropriate interval.

Depending on the fit of `p` to the data, it's possible for `p` not to be monotonic over the interval of interest, which presents problems since there will be more than one prediction for `x` given `y`.  In such a case, the research may have to examine thoroughly the situation and determine any number of things, including the suitability of the fitted polynomial.

Answer (score 5):

Get some coefficients:

```
{a0, a1, a2, a3, a4} = RandomReal[1, 5]
(* {0.59997, 0.0773325, 0.466742, 0.106902, 0.227533} *)
```

Define a function:

```
x[y_] := x /. NSolve[y == a0 + a1 x + a2 x^2 + a3 x^3 + a4 x^4, Reals]
```

Try it:

```
x[5.5]
(* {-2.04995, 1.82863} *)
```

Two solutions at `y==5.5` for these coefficients. Plot the first:

```
Plot[x[yy][[1]], {yy, 1, 10}]
```

To plot the second, change `[[1]]` to `[[2]]`. If the number of solutions changes, and you try to plot one this doesn't exist, it'll complain. You can get it to ignore these points by wrapping `Plot[]` in `Quiet[]`.

Comment: Thanks for providing a nice answer! Is there a way I can return this as a function? So $x(y)$?

Comment: `x[y_]` **is** a function. Please be clear what you want. That's the first rule of succeeding with *Mathematica*.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I require an equation: $x(y) = ...$

Comment: You mean you want a **formula**? You can do `Solve[y == a0 + a1 x + a2 x^2 + a3 x^3 + a4 x^4, x, Quartics -> False]` to trivially get all four solutions as `Root` objects (be sure you have no definitions of the coefficients hanging around). Or, if you want an incredibly messy, and possibly unstable, set of radical expressions, set `Quartics->True`. You'll have to sort out which are real after defining the coefficients.

Comment: `NSolve[y == a0 + a1 x + a2 x^2 + a3 x^3 + a4 x^4, x]`  yields formulae that are horribly unstable in an experiment.